# ESRI Javascript API: Looping to Build a Layer Selection Menu

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

For reference, please see this: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/map_dynamiclayerlist.html

But, unlike the ESRI example, I am loading several different Services and each Service has multiple Layers. So I have modified the ESRI code per the following:

```
var visible = [];
function buildLayerList() {           
   arrayUtils.forEach(map.layerIds, function (id) {
     var currLayer = map.getLayer(id); 
     var items = arrayUtils.map(currLayer.layerInfos, function (info, index) {
        if (info.defaultVisibility) {
                      visible.push(info.id);
        }
        return "<input type='checkbox' class='list_item'" + (info.defaultVisibility ? "checked=checked" : "") + "' id='" + info.id + "'' /><label for='" + info.id + "'>" + info.name + "</label>";
       });
  });
     //more code per ESRI
}
```

But, in my case, the `items` variable is not getting any values; it is returning as null or not defined. I presume that is because I have basically two loops, unlike ESRI's.

So how do I fix it? I would hate to hard-code the layer selection menu option but may have to if I cant figure this out.

Note: These are all Arcgis Dynamic Layers.

Thanks!

Comment: Well `items` is declared as a local variable inside the `.forEach` callback. Where are you trying to reference it?

Comment: Right below the //more code per ESRI--as in the original ESRI code

Comment: Well that's not going to work - a local variable is called "local" because its use is restricted to the scope in which it's declared. On top of that, your code reassigns `items` with the result of the `.map()` call on each iteration of the `.forEach()`. Even if you could access it, it would only contain the results of the last iteration.

Comment: Makes sense.So what to do?

Comment: I don't know what your overall goal is. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Create a layer selection checkbox option--just like in the ESRI linked page.

Comment: It'd probably be easier to accumulate the checkbox markup in an array like `visible` than to use `.map()`.

Comment: That's what I am thinking--make the items variable inside the function but outside of the loops

Comment: Okay, I have success making a new array items_cb and then making a 'push' to it to build the checkboxes; formatting is aweful: All in one row. But I will figure out and post here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never mind: All I needed was a Esri Javascript API's 'TOC Widget'; I downloaded that and implemented in my code. Much easier than trying to re-invent the wheel.
Thanks--especially to @Pointy.